# How to read a decimal from pc.scanf in c?

Tags: c, matlab, mbed

I am interfacing between MatLab and C, I can send an integer to C by in Matlab writing:

```
fprintf(mbed, '1', 'async');
```

(The serial port by which an mbed computer is attached is defined as mbed, that is where the C program is working from).

I then receive this in C with the line:

```
pc.scanf("%f",&inputFloat);
```

I then go on to try and use inputFloat in my program. This works perfectly well for integers, but the second that I try and do the same with non integers eg 0.5 or 1.5 it doesn't work.

Is there another way that I should try and receive the values from MatLab?

The only work around that I can currently see is to try and implement the code by sending two integers and then handling them in C by dividing one by the other, thereby sending every number as two integers.

Comment: Make sure you have support for floats in your embedded C environment. Many embedded standard libraries ship without support for scanning floats, since doing so requires a lot of code.

Comment: If you don't have float support, you could you use fixed-point notation, where for example `1.234` is represented by `1234`.